# Enable authentication on single node cassandra

Tags: authentication, cassandra

I am trying to enable authentication on cassandra (single node scenario) but when I enable PaswordAuthenticator, I run into into Quorun consistency leve is not satisfied. But If I can not login in the first place, how am I suppose to alter replication factor.

Comment: What version of Cassandra?

Comment: What is the output of the `nodetool status`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart all nodes with authentication enabled, and the login using default user `cassandra` with password `cassandra`:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Then change replication for `system_auth` keyspace, repair it, etc. Here are the [more detailed instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html).

Regarding the `QUORUM` error message - for single node cluster the quorum is equal to 1, so if you get this error, then it could be that you had other nodes in this cluster registered, but they weren't correctly removed.

Comment: I am only using one node, so there is no question of all nodes. And when I  cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra I get cqlsh localhost -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Error during authentication of user cassandra : org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)}). Now this is the problem and also I have enabled PasswordAuthentication

Comment: I just checked single node cluster running in Docker - everything works without any problems. I've updated the answer with more hints.